# How to find nth child of a record in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores categories and sub categories (self join)

```
The table structure is like this:
-CategoryId
-CategoryName
-ParentCategoryId
```

How to find nth child/childs of a category in sql query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like this

```
DECLARE @Categories TABLE(
        CategoryId INT, 
        CategoryName VARCHAR(20),
        ParentCategoryId INT
)

INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 1, '1',NULL
INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 2, '2',NULL

INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 3, '1.3',1
INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 4, '1.4',1

INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 5, '1.3.5',3
INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 6, '1.3.6',3
INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 7, '1.3.6.7',6

INSERT INTO @Categories SELECT 8, '1.4.8',4

DECLARE @CatID INT,
        @NthLevel INT
SELECT  @CatID = 1,
        @NthLevel = 2

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                1 AS CatLevel
        FROM    @Categories c 
        WHERE   CategoryId IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.*,
                CatLevel + 1 AS CatLevel
        FROM    Vals v INNER JOIN
                @Categories c   ON  c.ParentCategoryId =  v.CategoryID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
WHERE   CatLevel = @NthLevel
```

This will recursively build the tree structure, and limit it on the tree level you are looking for.

Comment: +1 Now that the question is edited to say "nth child/childs" this answer makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ParentCategoryId,
  , CategoryId AS [n-th child]
FROM (
  SELECT CategoryId
    , ParentCategoryId
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentCategoryId ORDER BY CategoryId) as ChildNumber
  FROM Categories
) p
WHERE ChildNumber = %N
```

Comment: sorry, this didnt work. i'm not looking for the nth record from the table, what i need is the nth child of a category

Comment: I believe it does exactly this. It returns n-th child for each ParentCategoryId in the table.

Comment: i tried this again, didn't work. Its just partition over ParentId. Anyway thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

To find the `N`th child, ordered by CategoryId, of category `M`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by c.CategoryId) as rn
        ,       c.*
        from    Categories p
        join    Categories c
        on      p.CategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId
        where   p.CategoryId = M
        )
where   rn = N
```